# MySQL PreparedStatement: Parameter index out of range

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I'v searched during one hour trough stackoverflow and couldn't find an answer to my problem (Well, there's people having the same error, but not exactly like mine).

So here's the code:

```
    public synchronized static void setAllData(String player, String xp, String lvl, String coins, String won, String lost, String kills, String deaths, String redput, String blueput, String time)
{
    try
    {
        PreparedStatement sql =
        connection.prepareStatement("UPDATE `" + Main.table + "` SET `xp` = ?, lvl` = ?,  `towercoins` = ?, `won` = ?, `lost` = ?, `kills` = ?, `deaths` = ?, `redput` = ?, `blueput` = ?, `time` = ? WHERE `player` = ?;");
        sql.setString(1, xp);
        sql.setString(2, lvl);
        sql.setString(3, coins);
        sql.setString(4, won);
        sql.setString(5, lost);
        sql.setString(6, kills);
        sql.setString(7, deaths);
        sql.setString(8, redput);
        sql.setString(9, blueput);
        sql.setString(10, time);
        sql.setString(11, player);
        sql.executeUpdate();
        sql.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And i have this error every time:

> Java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (2 > number of
>   parameters, which is 1).

I don't get it since all parameters are here etc... so why ?

Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems like you missing the opening quote on this statement.

```
SET `xp` = ?, lvl` = ?,
```

Answer (score 0):

it would  be like this
connection.prepareStatement("UPDATE `" + Main.table + "` SET `xp` = ?, `lvl` = ?,  `towercoins` = ?, `won` = ?, `lost` = ?, `kills` = ?, `deaths` = ?, `redput` = ?, `blueput` = ?, `time` = ? WHERE `player` = ?;");

Comment: Thanks but the problem is like kucing_terbang said, i missed a `